# Joomla front page multiple modules/articles

Tags: module, joomla2.5, virtuemart, article, frontpage

I have a Joomla website with virtuemart. The front page has featured products. Now I want to be able to show more at my front page. I made an article with a picture in it. I want it also to display at the homepage at the same time as the featured products module, say above it. So basically multiple things at the front page. Now I could hardcode it in, but I want to be able to make it as article as it is easier and faster editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is Module,

Just create a module , with params as article id options.
Means create a module with parameter option that you can set the article Id, then simply assign that module to the Home Page.

Inside your module Just read the article  id and fetch those article details.

For the [module development tutorial](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial) you can check this.

Hope its helps..